Problems using tensorflow

<Cell In[34], line 45>

45 import tensorflow

File c:\Users\tonfo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py:46

46 from ._api.v2 import internal
47 from ._api.v2 import operators
48 from ._api.v2 import audio

File c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v2_internal_.py:10

10 from . import dispatch

<TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was () -> handle>

Hi@ต้นฝน,The error message you're encountering—TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was () -> handle—suggests a problem with TensorFlow's internal code or an issue with the environment configuration.Make sure TensorFlow is correctly installed and that there are no version conflicts. Package conflicts or incomplete installations can sometimes lead to these issues. Reinstalling TensorFlow might be necessary to address any underlying problems.

Ensure that your TensorFlow version is compatible with your Python version. TensorFlow 2.10.1 supports Python versions 3.7 to 3.10, but you are using Python 3.11, which may not be fully compatible with TensorFlow 2.10.1. Additionally, verify that environment variables related to TensorFlow and Python paths are correctly configured, as incorrect paths can sometimes cause issues.
